# SPI - latch on trailing edge detail

Tags: spi

I am asking in general about SPI. What does "Shift transmit data on the leading clock edge, latch on trailing edge" means? Does this means that data changes when Clock goes from High To Low. (This is for setting Phase control)As far as clock polarity is concerned, leading edge is low to high transition and idle clock line is low.
Please could someone explain this.

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus#Clock_polarity_and_phase It is as simple as it can get

Comment: Answer readily available with a Google search. Question should be closed.

Comment: Should we answer the question which are likely to be closed? e.g. This one!

Comment: actually ... i dont understand the term "latch on trailing edge". Does this means data will be maintained or changed at trailing edge?? I know im asking silly question. But I am confused.

Comment: It means the transmitter (be it master or slave) will load the data onto its output on the leading (rising) edge, and the receiver will read its value (latch) on the trailing (falling) edge. So the data changes on the rising edge.

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to (which I don't find confusing at all) basically talks of clock polarity and data sampling related implementation. Should you read and understand CPOL and CPHA, this question is very much sated there itself, More importantly CPHA.

Referring to [wikipedia page for SPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus#Clock_polarity_and_phase),

[image]

The image clearly indicates, that regardless of the clock polarity, if you Set the CPHA, the data is sampled on the trailing (last) edge, and if you clear CPHA the data is sampled on the leading (first) edge of the SCK.

Comment: that's fine... but in layman term, what does "latch" means. "latch on trailing edge"??

Comment: @user123456: "latch" means in this case "read" or "store". Basically you should shift it into a D-flip-flop (DFF) on the trailing edge (as a DFF is a edge sensitive latch).